# How to create collection of objects and assign as value in another object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have 2 array as follows

```
Ids= ["1","2","3"] and Values = ["AA","BB","CC"]
```

I need to create objects of the format

```
Obj= {id:1,value:"AA"}
```

with the values in the arrays. Three such objects has to be formed and assigned as propery of another object as follows in objectdata

```
var data={ "itemid" :1,
           "name" :"test",
            "objects": objectsdata }
```

This has to be done in javaScript. How to achive this?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
var Ids= ["1","2","3"], Values = ["AA","BB","CC"], objectsdata = [], i;

for(i = 0; i < Ids.length; i++){
    objectsdata.push({
        id: Ids[i],
        value: Values[i]
    })
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6B4r6/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this out.

```
var a = {"a":"wohoo", 2:"hello2", "d":"hello"};
alert(a["a"]);
alert(a[2]);
alert(a["d"]);
```

Simple approach.I hope you are trying to implement a dictionary